# Замена списка слов в тексте

Tags: python

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такое: Нужно в тексте файла найти определённые слова и заменить их другими словами, слова, которые нужно найти содержатся в списке old_data, слова на которые нужно заменить в new_data

```
 old_data = ['qwe', '123', 'asd']
 new_data = ['qwe', '123', 'asd']
```

Для единичного случая когда у нас есть одно слово и зкаменить его нужно на одно слово, я написал ф-ю

```
  def Params(self, old_data, new_data, file):
    file = open(mapfile, 'r') 
    text = file.read() 
    file.close()
    file = open(mapfile, 'w')
    file.write(text.replace(old_data, new_data))
    file.close()
```

Все работает, но как сделать чтобы она брала два списка и работала с ними, я пока не понимаю, пробовал сделать с циклом, но у меня  неправильно заменяет, в том плане, что заменяет не все элемены или же потом дописывает лишние. В общем прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так, не очень красиво, но должно сработать:

```
def Params(self, old_data, new_data, file):
    file1 = open(mapfile, 'r') 
    file2 = open(mapfile, 'w')
    for line in file1.readlines():
        for word_number in range(len(old_data)):
            line.replace(old_data[word_number], new_data[word_number])
        file2.write(line)
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
```

UPD:

```
def Params(self, old_data, new_data, mapfile):
    file = open(mapfile, 'r') 
    text = file.read() 
    file.close()
    for word_number in range(old_data):
        text.replace(old_data[word_number], new_data[word_number])
    file = open(mapfile, 'w') 
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Там одно из условий, чтобы один файл использовался.

Comment: ну а если второй вариант?

Comment: запуская Ваш второй вариант вылазиет ошибка:
       File "models.py", line 20, in Params
          for word_number in range(old_data):
           TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.

Не подскажите, уже тогда из-за чего это может происходить, так как вроде повода для ошибки вроде нет.

Comment: ну, конечно, там len(old_data) нужно. Я поправил выше. Просто я не проверял, на коленке быстро написал=) Там нужен не массив, а количество элементов в нём.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!